# CSS: Is it possible to make an element look like a sine/cosine function?

Tags: html, css

On my page I want elements that will serve as horizontal "breaks" in the same way as `hr` elements, but I would like them to be shaped like a sine function.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Here's a fiddle for you to complete: http://jsfiddle.net/pdov7u85/

HTML:

```
<p>Here's some red text</p>
<!--some element with id someElement will go here-->
 <p>Here's some blue text, which should be divided from the red text with a wavy line</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:nth-of-type(1)
{
    color: red;
}

#someElement
{

}

p:nth-of-type(2)
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I'd use an SVG but that's just me. No need to overthink things here

Comment: You can create an image that contains a period of a sine or cosine function and set it as background for an element (pseudo-element if desired) and make it repear in the x direction. But did you expect to be able to create a graph of a sine function in CSS?

Comment: Back in Days of Yore (like, 1999 or so), people used to use ugly gifs to make these kinds of horizontal page breaks. Why don't you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Challenge accepted.

```css
.sine { 
 text-align: center;
}
.sine_span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height: 20px;
 width: 40px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.sine_span_first {
 border-bottom: none;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
 transform: translate(-20px, 0) scale(2,1);
}
.sine_span_second {
 border-top: none;
 border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
 transform: translate(20px, 20px) scale(2,1);
}
.sine_span_first_2 {
  transform: translate(0, 20px) scale(1,2);
}
.sine_span_second_2 {
  transform: translate(0, 60px) scale(1,2);
}
```

```html
Flat curve
<div class="sine">
  <span class="sine_span sine_span_first"></span><span class="sine_span sine_span_second"></span>
</div>

<br />
Sharp curve
<div class="sine">
  <span class="sine_span sine_span_first sine_span_first_2"></span><span class="sine_span sine_span_second sine_span_second_2"></span>
</div>
```

Btw, shouldn't you use some gif image for this?

Comment: This does not produce a graph of a sine function.

Comment: You can play around with scaling and make it look more 'sine wave like'.  I've updated my example with another one, I hope you like it better.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could draw that sine function in javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (canvas == null || !canvas.getContext) {
    return;
}
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(11,153,11)";

for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {

    var x = i * 5;
    var y = Math.sin(5 * x + 1);
    ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x, 25 - y * 24);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddzfwy9g/1/)

Or you could just use an SVG image like Paulie_D suggested.

Comment: but doesnt use css and seems to need an explicit width declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is about ten years too late for OP, but I found this question while trying to figure out how to do the same thing as them (for a slightly different use case: I am making a silly little browser game where you are a jellyfish). The answers here don't really draw a useful sine wave, so I have summoned some code that does this effectively, with parameters that can be modified, and I've tested it to work quite well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Horiz sine</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const amplitude = 50; // Height of the wave
    const frequency = 0.05; // Frequency of the wave
    const phaseShift = 0; // Phase shift of the wave
    const verticalShift = canvas.height / 2; // Vertical position of the wave

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, verticalShift);

    for(let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
      const y = amplitude * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * frequency * x) + phaseShift) + verticalShift;
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    ctx.stroke();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

A modified version of this that draws a vertical sine wave, going down, is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vert sine</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const amplitude = 50; // Width of the wave
    const frequency = 0.05; // Frequency of the wave
    const phaseShift = 0; // Phase shift of the wave
    const horizShift = canvas.width / 2; // Horizontal position of the wave

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(horizShift, 0);

    for(let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
      const y = horizShift - amplitude * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * frequency * x) + phaseShift);
      ctx.lineTo(y, x);
    }

    ctx.stroke();
  </script>
</body>
```

You can mess around with the constants here to create differently shaped or positioned sine waves.

Answer (score -2):

As @Paulie_D said don't over think it.

Be semantic and use a HR, give it a height and a background image.

```
hr{ 
    border:none; 
    height:82px; 
    background:url('http://i60.tinypic.com/df8y75.png'); 
    background-size:50%;
  }
```

eg.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdov7u85/3/

note: background-size is not supported in older versions of IE but I only used it for convenience.