# CSS curved border

Tags: css, shapes

I wonder if is possible to make this shape using CSS or is better to draw an SVG.
Thanks[image]

Comment: It would theoretically be **possible** to make this shape using CSS, but it would be ridiculously complex. You'd be far better off using an SVG :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575797/css-is-it-possible-to-make-an-element-look-like-a-sine-cosine-function  Here is a good start.

Comment: Good post. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // begin custom shape
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(170, 80);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

      // complete custom shape
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```